# Is the description for the L'Chaim hat correct?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2012

It says that the requirement is:

> post or vote on December 16

Don't the hats start tomorrow? Or have I just not noticed the "Winter Bash" in the header for the last 2 days?

Comment: Some hats require a time machine.  [meta-tag:status-bydesign].

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Nope, hats started about an hour ago!

We wanted to celebrate Hannukah, but we couldn't make the deadlines work, so we opted to award the hat retroactively. That's basically the whole story!

Comment: Oh! One more piece: This is the ***only*** hat that will be awarded like this.

Comment: Odd. I did not receive one for SO even though I KNOW I voted on that day!

Comment: @AustinHenley Did you indicate [that you love hats on SO](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/joinin.png)?

Comment: Sorry, it was slow to show for SO for some reason :D

Comment: Yay! I both lit candles on the day and voted!

Comment: But why December 16th? What's so special about that day?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanukkah

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - You should know... last day of Hanukkah.

Comment: @Oded last candle was lit on Saturday evening, so I assumed this was the end of Hanukkah. Oh well!

Comment: Last candle was lit on Saturday night the 15th, which is the beginning of the day that continued through Dec 16 (sundown).  Dec 16 is the best way to line that up on the secular calendar (especially with Dec 15 being Shabbat :-) ).  @Aarthi, the L'chaim badge was a pleasant surprise -- thanks!

Comment: @MonicaCellio Hooray! :) -- For those unaware, Monica is a moderator on our [judaism.se] site. If anyone knows, it's her!