# Does progress towards hats only start when you enable it, or is it retrospective?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2012

Loving the hats!

So much so, that I'm trying to get one :).

I have already achieved the criteria for several of them, but **before** I enabled the hats functionality.

So my question is: Does the progress towards them start on enabling them, or will it back-date from before then?

Comment: Looks like it is retrospective, but that it takes time to get them (probably a batch job running every x minutes).

Comment: @Oded - [Every 5 minutes.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159196/how-much-time-does-it-take-to-award-any-hat/159209#comment461034_159198) :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unless I've misinterpreted [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159134/is-the-description-for-the-lchaim-hat-correct#comment460826_159137), L'chaim is the only hat that's awarded retroactively. All other hats are based on your activity from the **19 December 2012 00:00 UTC** (and not the time when you opted in).

Answer (score 6):

Shawn Chin is correct -- L'Chaim is the *only* hat being awarded for activity that started before the event began.

All hats must be earned with activity that occurred *after* **19 December 2012 00:00 UTC**.

Comment: So all activity from 19 December 2012 00:00 UTC to when I actually enable those awesome hats still count?

Comment: @ShawnChin Yes! Even if you decide you love hats later, your activity counter started at midnight UTC on 19 December. :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've updated my answer to make this more explicit.

Answer (score 3):

I earned the L'chaim hat (on main site) as soon as I enabled hats today so it definitely back-dates this one seeing as that badge was for posts or votes on the 16th :)

I have a feeling that some may not be back-dated however such as making 5 edits. You will likely have to earn these through meeting the defined criteria after you have opted in to the winter bash.