# Can score/views hats be earned on questions/answers that already exist?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does progress towards hats only start when you enable it, or is it retrospective?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159278/does-progress-towards-hats-only-start-when-you-enable-it-or-is-it-retrospective)

Can I earn the [Gangnam Style](http://winterba.sh/gangnam-style) series, [Where Is He?](http://winterba.sh/where-is-he) series, or [Guide My Sleigh](http://winterba.sh/guide-my-sleigh) series hats on questions or answers that were posted before Winter Bash opened, or only on new posts?  It isn't clear from the Winter Bash hat description page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hats can *only* be earned with activity performed *after* **19 December 2012 00:00 UTC**. The exception to this is the L'Chaim hat, due to what it's celebrating and our own constraints.

Basically: get to posting! :D