# how one can win the hat L'chaim

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the description for the L’Chaim hat correct?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159134/is-the-description-for-the-lchaim-hat-correct)

How one can win the hat L'chaim on [winter bash](http://winterba.sh/), as its description says "post or vote on December 16" and in [FAQ](http://winterba.sh/faq) it is mentioned in question "What is going on? Why do I see hats?" that "From December 19th until January 4th"

Comment: @BhuvanRikka - No it's not a bug. It's correct information.

Comment: Okay... Sorry..

Comment: Im still wondering of `l'chaim` is the right greeting for Chanukkah. And the hat should almost certainly been in the shape of a donut!

Comment: What does this hat look like? I mean, I got it (on another site) but I can't see any difference in my avatar.

Comment: Stop removing the possible duplicate text!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's retrospective.

If you didn't post on December 16<sup>th</sup> you can't win the hat.

Comment: I did, though! Yay, hats!

Comment: So, slightly easier to get than the [precognitive badge](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/892/precognitive) on SO, at least!