# How can people who did not vote on December 16th get the LChaim hat?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the description for the L’Chaim hat correct?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159134/is-the-description-for-the-lchaim-hat-correct)

How can people who did not vote on December 16th get the LChaim hat?

I am just curious :-)

I assume that it is a Hanukkah themed hat, so it was recieved on Hanukkah, but there were no hats then! And it was a Sunday.

^_^

[Must remember to get the new years and xmas hats fyi :-P]

Comment: From now on we have to vote every single day, just in case!

Comment: @BoPersson I guess so :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They can't. If you posted that day, you were awarded the hat today, otherwise you were not.

Think of it as the Winter Bash equivalent of the [Precognitive badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/892/precognitive).

Comment: Hehe I wonder why the chose the **Sunday** of Hanukkah. Shouldn't it have been *any* post during the holiday? ^_^

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA they [wanted to do that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159137/152859), but schedule was too tight: "We wanted to celebrate Hannukah, but we couldn't make the deadlines work"

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd eh? what do u mean? just set the script to find all during the 8 days of Hanukkah :-P

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA sorry, thought you meant why they didn't activate the hats sooner. :/

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd nope ^_^

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA kk, for the record Sunday was the last official day of Hanukkah that's all.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I know that :-P but sunday was a sunday

Comment: @Amanaplan Also, 8 days' worth of activity? Literally everyone would have a hat. That's a lot of hats! We awarded over a thousand immediately to begin with, and that's just people who said yes within a couple of hours of launch!

Comment: @Aarthi hehe so a free head start ^_^

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA: A *hat* start..

Comment: @MartijnPieters **awesome**

Comment: @MartijnPieters for the win. just all the wins.